# How can i force delete list item by powershell?

Tags: sharepoint

When i want to delete list item, sharepoint return this error.

The server has encountered the following error(s):
Item does not exist. The page you selected contains an item that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

I have admin permission and alson try to delete item by pnp powershell.

Remove-PnPListItem -List "Orders" -Identity "22" -Force -Recycle

Return

Remove-PnPListItem : Item does not exist.
The page you selected contains an item that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
At line:1 char:2

- Remove-PnPListItem -List "Orders" -Identity "22" -Force -Recycle
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Remove-PnPListItem], ServerException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.RemoveListItem
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can first check whether the item exists in the list

```
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName = "list/library name"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Method 1: View all items in the list/library
#Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName 

#Method 2: Determine if there is this item
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Id 22
```

[image]

If the item does not exist, an error will be reported even if you force delete the item